# Customrenderer android to remove tabbedpage navbar icon and reduce fontsize

Tags: android, xamarin

So basically i have a standard navigationbar in a tabbedpage. Where i call the items like: `<local:name></local:name>`

On iOS it looks great, but on Android, the text gets cut off, and the icons are too big.

- I want to remove the icons from the navigation bar, and scale down the text through a custom android renderer.

Since I'm really new at Xamarin, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how I should solve this.. Until now I have the following:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Navigation), typeof(CustomNav))]
namespace SiteManager.Droid
{
public class CustomNav : TabbedRenderer
{
    public CustomNav(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured that there is no need to do a custom renderer for this.

In order to remove the icons from the Android actionbar, simply put the following for each title on the content pages:

```
<ContentPage
Title="Page1">
<ContentPage.Icon>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
        <On
            Platform="iOS"
            Value="xx.png" />
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Icon>
```

In order to scale down the text, add the following in the droid/resources/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="tab_text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
<item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
```

and lastly, reference it in the Tabbar.axml like:

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_text"
```